# onload Function and Document Ready function in JS creating conflict

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm working on a section of my Website which has a TODO List built in not I want the data to load just like other data that are loading alongside the page. I tried having onload in Body Tag in my HTML and I had also tried to `$(document).ready(function(){})` as well however neither of them seemed to work nor was I getting any errors in my console. But the function is working as it is also link to another function which runs on click of a button which I don't want to keep happening. I want it to be seamless. Is there any reason why this might not be working.

Thanks for any help in advance.

My HTML and Javascript Code:

```js
function create() {
   unfinished_task_container = document.getElementById("main_container");
   unfinished_task_container.innerHTML = "";

   var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   var uid;
   if (user != null) {
    uid = user.uid;
  }

  task_array = [];
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("/Users/" + uid + "/todo/")
    .once("value", (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        task_array.push(Object.values(childData));
      });
    for (var i = 0; i < task_array.length; i++) {
      task_key = task_array[i][0];
      task_title = task_array[i][1];

      //Data
      task_container = document.createElement("div");
      task_container.setAttribute("class", "task_container");
      task_container.setAttribute("data-key", task_key);

      task_data = document.createElement("div");
      task_data.setAttribute("id", "task_data");

      title = document.createElement("p");
      title.setAttribute("id", "task_title");
      title.setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
      title.innerHTML = task_title;

      //Tools
      task_tool = document.createElement("div");
      task_tool.setAttribute("id", "task_tool");

      task_done_button = document.createElement("button");
      task_done_button.setAttribute("id", "task_done_button");
      task_done_button.setAttribute(
        "onclick",
        "task_done(this.parentElement.parentElement, this.parentElement)"
      );
      task_done_button.setAttribute("onclick", "task_done()");
      fa_done = document.createElement("i");
      fa_done.setAttribute("class", "fa fa-check");

      unfinished_task_container.append(task_container);
      task_container.append(task_data);
      task_data.append(title);

      task_container.append(task_tool);
      task_tool.append(task_done_button);
      task_done_button.append(fa_done);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<body onload="create();">
<div class="dentistToDo">
  <p class="divlable">Your Personal To Do List</p>
  <input id="input_box" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
  <button id="input_button" onclick="add_task()">Add Task</button>
  <div class="container" id="main_container">
    <!-- DIV for TODO List -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your problem `task_done_button` not working? Please try to create a [mcve]

Comment: Hmm not really that section has been handled the issue is that I want this section of my JS to be loaded when the HTML loads but for some reason this function is not working onLoad.